# 3D rubber sheeting using ground control points

Tags: grass-gis, vector, 3d, ogr2ogr, orthorectification

I have 3d lines that I would like to rubber sheet or rectify in 3D (including z rectification). I used ogr2ogr with -gcp, however all the vertex of a polyline were set to a single elevation, and since you don't input a z for reference I am guessing it does not rubber sheet in 3D.

```
ogr2ogr feat_rect.shp feat_in.shp -gcp 765825.824 2169178.054 765820.33 2169177.15 413.5 -gcp 765849.205 2169176.512 765846.487 2169174.837 -gcp ...
```

It seems like GRASS `v.rectify` could do it, however I'd like a solution where I don't need to setup a GRASS workspace and rather run it in batch mode. ESRI solution could also be acceptable if I can run it in batch mode.

Answer (score 1):

You can run GRASS GIS in a complete batch mode which includes the temporary creation of the workspace (just need to know the EPSG code of the actual projection or simply use the metadata provided by your SHAPE file, i.e. the .prj file).

See for examples:
http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly

See therein "Python: GRASS GIS 7 without existing location using metadata only" for a almost copy-paste example.

Comment: I didn't know that you could run GRASS in batch mode !